# not able to recieve incoming calls

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Myy phone model is HTC desire 526 g plus.when I rang called it from another phone  in showed ring is going but on the phone message appeared,"Unfortunately the process com.android.phone has stopped. Very confused. I remember I installed an app call name announcer. First it worked but after few minutes this problem has risen.NEED UR HELP pls do reply

Comment: The inbuilt app named "Phone" has the name `com.android.phone`. I don't know what's causing the crash but you may try "Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> Phone -> Clear Data -> Clear Cache".

Answer (score 1):

If the call name announcer did in fact cause a crash, try removing that app first, and have someone call you again. If it is still crashing, follow @Firelord's advice, clear the data and cache of the phone app, and perhaps try turning the phone off and on again.

Lastly, if you are STILL getting this problem, try doing a factory reset. If THAT doesn't fix the problem, go back to wherever you got the phone and ask for a new one.